# What means skipNegotiation in SignalR HubConnection?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, websocket, signalr

What is the diference between

```
this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
  .withUrl(environment.API_URL + "invoicinghub", {
    skipNegotiation: true,
    transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets
  })
  .withAutomaticReconnect([0, 2000, 10000, 30000, null])
  .build();
```

and

```
this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
  .withUrl(environment.API_URL + "invoicinghub", {     
    transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets
  })
  .withAutomaticReconnect([0, 2000, 10000, 30000, null])
  .build();
```

What does this skipNegotiation : true.

Thanks!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/%40aspnet/signalr/ihttpconnectionoptions?view=signalr-js-latest#skipnegotiation

Comment: yes, but what it does?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In SignalR, the client first sends a negotiation request to the server and the server responds with a redirect URL and an access token if there is one.

**Client Request**

```json
{
  "connectionId":"807809a5-31bf-470d-9e23-afaee35d8a0d",
  "availableTransports":[
    {
      "transport": "WebSockets",
      "transferFormats": [ "Text", "Binary" ]
    },
    {
      "transport": "ServerSentEvents",
      "transferFormats": [ "Text" ]
    },
    {
      "transport": "LongPolling",
      "transferFormats": [ "Text", "Binary" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Server Response**

```json
{
    "url":"https://test.service.signalr.net/client/?hub=chat&...",
    "accessToken":"<a typical JWT token>"
}
```

Only after receiving the response from the server does the client establish a connection.

In SignalR Core, but not in SignalR ASP, this requires sticky sessions.  To avoid using sticky sessions, the client needs to skip negotiation but is restricted to only using `websockets` without Azure.

Sources:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-concept-internals#client-connections
- https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/blob/release/2.2/specs/TransportProtocols.md

Comment: I'm having issues with instance stickiness/affinity so I'm trying to figure out if it's okay if we skip negotiation in our application. In what cases would we want a redirect URL and an access token?

Comment: @JustinHarris I haven't worked much with SignalR Core, only with SignalR ASP.  You can try to skip it like the example in the question and see what happens.  I would assume that the redirectURL and access token would work automatically.  I suggest creating a new question with your specific setup.